# change date format in resultset

Tags: date, format

I'm fetching results from oracle table and want to set the specific date format which is dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm.

I dont know at which place  or column position date is stored.

I tried to check column types and change the date but this operation is time consuming.

How to convert this date?

Below is my code:

```
    if((colType.get(num).equalsIgnoreCase("DATE")))
                    {
                        String getDate = rs.getString(colName.get(num));
                        String convertedDate = "";
                        if(getDate!=null||!getDate.isEmpty())
                            {
                                DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s");
                                SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
                                Date date = originalFormat.parse(getDate);
                                convertedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
                                bw.write(convertedDate);
                                bw.write("|");
                            }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rs.getString(columnname)` instead of `rs.getString(columnnumber)`

But I guess what you really want is one of these two:

- `ResultSet.getMetaData()` which contains information about the columns, names and data types, good for filling dynamic tables or grids
- `rs.getObject(clumnnumber/name)`. You can test the result using `instanceof` and handle dates separatly. Everything else can be returned using `toString()`